# Mocked ReactiveX streams and Singles doesn't emit elements

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, rx-java, reactivex

I am testing some functionality based on RxJava using Mockito to mock objects. I have a place where I need to mock a value for returning method which is `Single<HttpResponse<Buffer>>` but when I do this no element is emitted from that `Single`. I checked values in debugger and it seems to be the same object (the one mocked in the beginning and the other, returned from the method that should emit a value). But it doesn't behave as expected and my stream ends empty.

Here are my mocks and returning rules:

```
WebClient webClient = mock(WebClient.class);
HttpRequest<Buffer> httpRequest = mock(HttpRequest.class);
HttpResponse<Buffer> httpResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);

when(httpResponse.statusCode()).thenReturn(200);
when(httpResponse.bodyAsString()).thenReturn(String.format("{\"%s\" : \"%s\"}", "address", testAddress));
when(httpRequest.addQueryParam(any(), any())).thenReturn(httpRequest);
when(httpRequest.rxSend()).thenReturn(Single.just(httpResponse)); // this returned Single doesn't emit the value
when(webClient.post(any())).thenReturn(httpRequest);
```

Other mocked objects are returned correctly, these are `webClient`, `httpRequest` and `httpResponse`. The `Single` I am talking about is also returned correctly (it holds a mocked object in `value` field, I checked that in debugger) but It doesn't emit it.

The emission should happen here:

```
@Override
public Single<String> registerUserWallet(String userHash) {

    Single<HttpResponse<Buffer>> test = httpClient.post(EthereumApiEndpoints.MANAGED_ACCOUNT.uri)
            .addQueryParam("path", userHash)
            .rxSend();

    return test
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> log.debug("debug")) // none of this logs are printed out
            .doOnEach(x -> log.debug("debug"))
            .doOnError(x -> log.debug("debug"))
            .doOnSuccess(x -> log.debug("debug"))
            .flatMap(this::handleResponse);
}
```

I created `test` variable to check its value in debugger. Every objects are in place, `httpRequest` and httpResponse`work well, the problem is with emission of`Single> test`.

Edit: The method where the `Single` is used:

```
private Observable<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<UserWallet, String>> mapWalletWithAddress(UserWallet wallet) {

        return userWalletDao.findFirstRegisteredWalletsForUserInNetwork(wallet.getUserId(),
                blockchainIntegration.getNetwork())
                .map(UserWallet::getAddress)
                .doOnNext(alreadyRegisteredAddress -> log.info("Found already registered address for user " +
                        "{} in {} network", wallet.getUserId(), blockchainIntegration.getNetwork()))
                .onErrorResumeNext(blockchainIntegration.registerUserWallet(wallet.getUserId()).toObservable()
                        .doOnNext(generatedAddress -> log.info("Generated new address {} for user {}.",
                                generatedAddress, wallet.getUserId())))
                .map(walletAddress -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(wallet, walletAddress))
                .doOnNext(walletAddressPair -> log.info("Mapped wallet {} with address {}.",
                        walletAddressPair.getKey(), walletAddressPair.getValue()));
    }
}
```

I am trying to find what is wrong for hours. I hope you guys will find it in a no time.

Comment: Most likely you have not subscribed to the returned `Single`.

Comment: @akarnokd It is flatMapped, and subscribed at the end.
Pardon, it is returned in `onErrorResumeNext()`

Comment: Perhaps you do not have an error so `onErrorResumeNext` does not switch to its fallback.

Comment: You were right! There were no error, but an empty Observable returned, I switched `onErrorResumeNext` to `switchIfEmpty` :)